# how to solve error replacement has 0 rows, data has 200 for a loop

Tags: r, loops, dataframe

I have 3 df which I put them in a list. For each df, I adjust values in a `zvar` function. Then I want to run a model and then resampling for the model in a loop applying the `zvar`.

But I encounter this error:

> Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "var2", value = numeric(0)) : 
>     replacement has 0 rows, data has 200

The message says that a variable does not exist, but I am able to print each variable in the dataframe, what is the issue here?

My df sample (all continuous vars):

```
  var1     var2
   2        2
   1        2
   9        7
```

My code:

```
zvar <- function(data, mean, sd){
     data$var2 <- (data$var2 - mean$var2)/sd$var2
     data$var1 <- (data$var1 - mean$var1)/sd$var1
     return(data)
 }
 # its args are automatically calculated in the following function `boot.fiml`.


dflist <- list(group1, group2, group3)

for (i in dflist) {
   i <- data.frame(i)
   print(i$var2)
   print(i$var1)
   m_group <- lm(var1 ~ var2, data = i)
   print(m_group)

   ## previous lines run successfully, not not the following one
   boot.fiml(data = i, model = m_group, R = 10, z.function = zvar)
 }
```

Thanks!

Comment: `i` is your `for` loop index variable; you then re-define `i` as the `list` element (which is a `data.frame`) as you loop through the entries of `dflist`. That may be the reason for the error.

Comment: What package is `boot.fiml` coming from? I think `i <- data.frame(i)` is unnecessary, assuming each element of `dflist` is a `data.frame`.

Comment: Also, `data$var2 <- (data$var2 - mean$var2)/sd$var2` is (I think) a bad way of programming. Why are you replacing the variable you are working on? You should probably return a different object than the one you are reading. Those two lines can be summed into: `return(data.frame(var2 = (data$var2 - mean$var2)/sd$var2), var1 = (data$var1 - mean$var1)/sd$var1)`